# Is it possible to preprocess the URL before mapping routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, url-routing

We're migrating a site from a proprietary framework to Ruby on Rails (v2.3).  The current framework sometimes puts /base/ at the start of the URL for no discernible reason, and I'd like the existing URL to work, even though we won't give it out any more.

My current solution, which I don't like, is to define the routes once on the main map and once on a 'base' scope:

```
def draw_routes(map)
  # do my routing here
end

ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.with_options :path_prefix => '/base' do |base|
    draw_map(base)
  end

  draw_map(map)
end
```

what I'd like to do is something like:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.strip 'base'

  # do my routing here
end
```

is there a solution of that form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a middleware to remove the base from the url.
In lib/remove_base.rb:

```
class RemoveBase
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    env['REQUEST_PATH'].gsub!(/^\/base/, '')
    env['PATH_INFO'].gsub!(/^\/base/, '')
    env['REQUEST_URI'].gsub!(/^\/base/, '')
    @status, @headers, @response = @app.call(env)
    [@status, @headers, self]
  end

  def each(&block)
    @response.each(&block)
  end
end
```

and add this line in config/environment.rb

```
config.middleware.use "RemoveBase"
```

I've tested it in 2.3.8 with mongrel, and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could simply do something like:

```
map.connect 'base/:controller/:action/:id'
```

That should route you to the right controller, action and id.

Comment: ah - should have said, I'm not using the standard :controller/:action/:id routes.  I have a long list of map.connect statements that I don't want to have to duplicate.